# AWS elastic beanstalk deploy always fails (uploading a zipfile)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I upload a new version of my app as a zipfile and click deploy. Then the status changes to severe.

This is the error trace:

```
WARN
Environment health has transitioned from Info to Degraded. Command failed on all instances. Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "Sample" (deployment 2). Application update failed 10 seconds ago and took 4 minutes.

ERROR
During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

ERROR
Failed to deploy application.

ERROR
Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i------'. Aborting the operation.

ERROR
[Instance: i-002326d7ceeba0ea9] Command failed on instance. Return code: 
1 Output: nginx: [emerg] no host in upstream ":80" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf:
2 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed Failed to start nginx, abort deployment. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.sh failed. 
For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

ERROR
Failed to start nginx, abort deployment
```

/var/log/eb-activity.log 
here are errors in this log:

```
[0mInstalling dependencies from Pipfile.lock (5e00f3)â€¦
  Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-lp47FrbD/bin/python: not found
...
[2020-05-29T01:51:24.746Z] INFO  [11395] - [Application update v1.3.3-1@3/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over null (null)
  a2f568b1c255eb9e0fdc6ceebdd29b9ec64b9ab4481a3e1c5bcb11828b0ac526
[2020-05-29T01:51:24.747Z] INFO  [11395] - [Application update v1.3.3-1@3/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01flip.sh] : Starting activity...
[2020-05-29T01:51:26.099Z] INFO  [11395] - [Application update v1.3.3-1@3/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01flip.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: nginx: [emerg] no host in upstream ":80" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf:2
  nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
  Failed to start nginx, abort deployment (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: nginx: [emerg] no host in upstream ":80" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf:2
  nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
  Failed to start nginx, abort deployment (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
...
[2020-05-29T01:51:26.099Z] INFO  [11395] - [Application update v1.3.3-1@3/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01flip.sh] : Activity failed.
[2020-05-29T01:51:26.099Z] INFO  [11395] - [Application update v1.3.3-1@3/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Activity failed.
[2020-05-29T01:51:26.099Z] INFO  [11395] - [Application update v1.3.3-1@3/AppDeployStage1] : Activity failed.
[2020-05-29T01:51:26.100Z] INFO  [11395] - [Application update v1.3.3-1@3] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
```

The inability to deploy has been consistent for this environment, after several attempts, even reverting to an older version.

Comment: Seems something wrong with the nginx. Do you overwrite its config file or change its settings in your deployment package?

Comment: Can you share your configuration file? Do you use `eb deploy` or AWS console for deployment? I also got problems while I was trying to compress the source code and deploy using the AWS console but `eb deploy` did the job for me unless you don't have any misconfiguration in the configuration file.

Comment: I undid all .elasticbeanstalk and YML overrides and got the same error. Best as I can tell, there was a problem with NGINX and the error messages were useless. After deploying this in a local docker image, I was able to see some startup dependency errors and stop most of these problems. But still not working - now, because the code uses too much memory or disk space and I can't isolate THOSE error messages in logs either.

Comment: I zipped code and uploaded to the EB console. I did not use `eb deploy`. I could try that, but as I noted, isolating the code and error messages using a local docker image resolved this. Running the code on my machine outside of docker did NOT reveal any problems, because the `pip` / `pipenv` part was missing some depdendency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afterwards, I resolved this by isolating the code and error messages using a local docker image with the zipfile. Running the code on my machine outside of docker did NOT reveal any problems, because the `pip` / `pipenv` part was missing some depdendency.

**Steps for local docker testing:**

WITHIN a docker container:

```
docker system prune
```

Go to the folder with `Dockerfile`

```
docker image build -t <app_name>:<version_number> .
```

TO run locally:
   (`docker rm <app_name>` first, if you've already got a stopped container with the same name from prior testing)

```
docker container run --publish 80:80 --name <app_name> myapp:1.0
```

NOTE:
    this won't let you test AWS functions that require environment variables, such as ~.aws credentials because they're not inside the image.
        (but you could add them with your `Dockerfile`)

Once the docker container is running, you'll see (I saw) error messages that were not there when testing locally, because they were caused by a missing package dependency and a `pipenv` error.

Comment: and since this is a webapp, you can open a browser to `0.0.0.0:8000` and test API endpoints, assuming you are using flask with a default port of 8000.